# Changing MoodText with skype.SendCommand doesn't work | SKYPE API C#

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

I've tried to change the Mood Text on my skype account with SKYPE API (C#), but it just doesn't change it.

```
Skype skype = new Skype();
skype.Attach();

Thread.Sleep(1000);
skype.SendCommand(new Command(0, "SET PROFILE _MOOD_TEXT " +moodText ));
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

I saw that code, but it doesn't work.

Also I've tried `"SET PROFILE RICH_MOOD_TEXT"`, but with no success either.
Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you see any error messages or exceptions?

Comment: no, everything seems right when i use break point , but it just doesnt change the mood text

Answer (score 2):

```
Skype x = new Skype();
x.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText = "Your mood text or string here!";
```

Pretty easy to do, it's the same with VB.net just minus the ";".

Answer (score 0):

SET PROFILE MOOD_TEXT

```
Skype skype = new Skype();
skype.Attach();

Thread.Sleep(1000);
skype.SendCommand(new Command(0, "SET PROFILE MOOD_TEXT " +moodText ));
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```